# Is the proper time invariant while going from stationery frame to freely falling frame in Genral Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems, time, observers

While reading GTR, I found the following calculation:

Consider an arbitrary gravitational field and let us take $x^{\mu}$ as the stationery/lab frame and $\xi^{\mu}$ as the freely falling frame, where the effects of gravity disappear, as permissable by principle of equivalence.
The proper time in the freely falling frame is :

$\partial \tau^2 = -\eta_{\alpha\beta}\partial \xi^\alpha \partial \xi^\beta$

In the stationery frame, the proper time can be expressed as:

$\partial \tau^2 = -\eta_{\alpha\beta}\frac{\partial \xi^\alpha}{\partial x^\mu} \partial x^\mu \frac{\partial \xi^\beta}{\partial x^\nu} \partial x^\nu $

$ = -g_{\mu\nu}\partial x^\mu \partial x^\nu $   where $g_{\mu \nu}= -\eta_{\alpha\beta}\frac{\partial \xi^\alpha}{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial \xi^\beta}{\partial x^\nu} $

So, it seems like the proper time is taken as equal in both the frames and only it's form is manipulated but, as far as I know, the proper time only remains invariant under lorentz tranformation while going from one inertial frame to another. So, why is the proper time taken the same here while going from an inertial frame (freely falling frame) to a non-inertial frame (stationery frame)?

Answer (score 3):

Proper time is the reading on a clock and as such it is a direct observable. All direct observables, are invariants. This should be clear since if a direct observable were frame variant then it would violate the principle of relativity.

Since proper time is a direct observable and since all direct observables are frame invariant, proper time is therefore frame invariant. This is regardless of whether the frame is inertial or not and whether the spacetime is flat or curved.

Comment: As per Steven Weinberg ( Gravitation and Cosmology), the fundamental property that distinguishes the Lorentz transfrmations is that they leave the proper time invariant. Since, Lorentz transformation only connects inertial frames then how is the proper time invariant while going to a non-inertial frame?

Comment: @D.Mason I think you have misunderstood Weinberg. Proper time is generally invariant, not just Lorentz invariant. What distinguishes the Lorentz transform is that they preserve the coordinate-based **form** of the spacetime interval formula. That is a much stronger property than simply the invariance of proper time.

Comment: Do mean the form of the formula $\partial \tau^2 = \eta_{\alpha \beta} \partial \xi^\alpha \partial \xi^\beta $ remains only for Lorentz transformation? And for other transformations the form of the equation changes but the value of $\partial \tau^2 $ remains constant?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, proper time is not generally invariant with respect to its special relativistic form (involving the Lorentz metric $\eta=diag(1,-1,-1,-1)$). But it can be **assumed** being an invariant (general scalar) if the metric is generalized to $g$. It is how $g$ is defined, basically.

You can, however, always find a point and a transformation such that $g=\eta$, locally (and moreover, the Levi-Civita pseudotensor assumes zero, locally), and that is the freely falling frame.

Comment: So, we define the g metric in such a way so as to keep the proper time invariant? Why do we do that?

Comment: Proper time is the period of time a comoving observer reads off of a clock, and being a comoving observer is clearly a term that does not depend on the coordinate system used (hence, it is invariant/scalar). You could, of course, also define a transform that maps proper time to the current score of an instance of Donkey Kong, but that would hardly be useful, and, moreover, would require additional information.

Comment: What is a comoving observer?

Comment: https://lmgtfy.app/?q=comoving+observer